# split style[hash].css into dynamically loaded chunks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, sass, lazy-loading

I am trying to split code of styles into smaller chunks due to the size of generated output. I am developing using `react` so i solved javascript loading with `React.lazy()`.

Lets say that there is one big application with 50 different views you can open. Not all views are available to all users.

What i did in my router is:

```
...
const view = React.lazy(() => import("./views/view"));
...

...
<view />
...
```

What this did is divided entire application to 50 separate `js` files that are dynamically loaded which is good.

It however did not divide styles the same way. So lets look into one of the views:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../../scss/view.scss";

class view extends Component {
    ...
}

export default view;
```

So each view has its own `scss` files dedicated for this view, which makes them virtually standalone. The problem is that webpack is still producing only one big `style[hash].css` file.

Webpack config:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    template: "./src/index.html",
    filename: "index.html"
});

const extractTextPlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: "css/style.[hash:8].css",
    allChunks: true
});

module.exports = {
    output: {
        filename: "js/main.[hash:8].js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: "babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|ico|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: "url-loader",
                options: {
                    limit: 25000,
                    outputPath: "/assets/",
                    name: "[name].[hash:8].[ext]"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(scss|sass|css)$/i,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: [
                        { loader: "css-loader" },
                        { loader: "postcss-loader", options: { sourceMap: true } },
                        { loader: "sass-loader", options: { sourceMap: true } }
                    ]
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json"]
    },
    plugins: [htmlPlugin, extractTextPlugin],
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: {
            rewrites: [{ from: /^\/$/, to: "/index.html" }]
        }
    }
};
```

Is there any way to make styles also produced and loaded dynamically respective to their js file, so for example if i open view 10 it loads `10.main[hash].js` and `10.style[hash].css` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to this problem is to replace deprecated `extract-text-webpack-plugin` package that is actually missing this functionality (splitting styles into respective chunks).

Instead `mini-css-extract-plugin` should be used and it automatically works.

updated working `webpack` config file:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    template: "./src/index.html",
    filename: "index.html",
});

const miniCssExtractPlugin = new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: "css/style.[hash:8].css",
    chunkFilename: "css/[id].style.[hash:8].css",
});

module.exports = {
    output: {
        filename: "js/main.[hash:8].js",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: "babel-loader",
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: "url-loader",
                options: {
                    limit: 25000,
                    outputPath: "/assets/",
                    name: "[name].[hash:8].[ext]",
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(scss|sass|css)$/i,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    "postcss-loader",
                    "sass-loader",
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json"],
    },
    plugins: [htmlPlugin, miniCssExtractPlugin],
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: {
            rewrites: [{ from: /^\/$/, to: "/index.html" }],
        },
    },
};
```